# Field has incomplete type?

Tags: c++, class

So I have to write this geometry project in which I have many header files. The program gives me this mistake upon compilation : `field 'p' has incomplete type`. I think that the problem is that the files are dependent on one another. These are the header files:

---

```
#ifndef POINT_H_INCLUDED
#define POINT_H_INCLUDED
#include "Line.h"
class Point
{
  friend class Line;
  friend class Vector;
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

 public:
   Point(double, double, double);
   Point ();
   Point (Line& , Line& );
   Point& operator=(Point&);
};


#endif // POINT_H_INCLUDED
```

---

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#include "Point.h"
class Point;
class Vector
{
  friend class Line;
  friend class Point;
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  public:
  Vector(double,double,double);
  Vector(Point&, Point&);
  Vector();
  Vector& operator=(Vector&);
};

#endif // VECTOR_H_INCLUDED
```

---

```
#ifndef LINE_H_INCLUDED
#define LINE_H_INCLUDED
#include "Point.h"
#include "Vector.h"

class Line
{
  Point p;
  Vector v;
  public:
  Line();
  Line(Point& , Vector&);
  Line(Point&,Point&);
};


#endif // LINE_H_INCLUDED
```

---

The mistake is given in the `Point.h` file. I'm working on CodeBlocks.

Comment: Quick note I just saw that in Line if I make it `Point* p ` it works, but why is that and how can I avoid it.

Comment: Why do you forward declare `class Point;` after actually including its header in Vector.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including *point.h* in *line.h* and vice versa, hence creating a **circular dependency**. Since in class `Point`, only `reference` to `Line` is used, you can exclude the header inclusion and just use forward declaration of `Line` class.

```
#ifndef POINT_H_INCLUDED
#define POINT_H_INCLUDED

//forward declare
class Line;
class Vector;

class Point
{
  friend class Line;
  friend class Vector;
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

 public:
   Point(double, double, double);
   Point ();
   Point (Line& , Line& );
   Point& operator=(Point&);
};


#endif // POINT_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the intersection point of two lines in the Point constructor is a bad design. Have a free standing function Point intersection(const Line&, const Line&) in the header "Line.h" and get rid of the circular dependency.